# jQuery-UI Dialog: How to make NONE of the action buttons "default"

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog

In jQuery-UI dialog box, the first button appears to be the default, therefore having focus set to itself.

But, this causes a frustrating effect, especially in Safari. Even in IE, you will see a rectangular selection mark around the button. Moreover, the *hover effect* will not be seen.

How can I set **NONE** of these buttons **as default** and therefore **NOT having focus set on any of them**?

Edit:

Examples can be seen at [jqueryui demo pages](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) and a snapshot using Safari is below.

[image: A snapshot from these pages]

I want to get rid of this blue selection.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be an css-class, that turns the button to "default".

Check with the Firebug Element Inspector what classes are applied to these buttons, and append the standard css class to all buttons of the form.

Comment: This might be case, but when you click to somewhere else, including FireBug interface, focus is immediately removed from this button, and you cannot research further.